# How does StringBuffer work? And why does it do this?

Tags: java, android

Here is what I have for my code:

```
        fis = openFileInput("MY_FILE");
        StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (fis.read(buffer) != -1) {
            fileContent.append(new String(buffer));
        }
        String myVariable = fileContent.toString().trim();
```

Why does StringBuffer require the bytes? How exactly does that work?

When setting the myVariable to the fileContent, why does it have extra whitespaces after the data? (Assuming MY_FILE contained a text "dad" )

Without the trim method, it would set the variable to :
dad

---

a ton of whitespace after dad. Even though the text file only says just "dad"

Comment: Also note that there are almost no situations where a StringBuffer is more appropriate than a StringBuilder. You should use a StringBuilder instead.

Comment: Its not touch directly your question, but why you use StringBuffer? Do you need thread safety? If not, use StringBuilder, its much faster.

Comment: @Divers , i'm still new to Android, what is the biggest different between StringBuffer and StringBuilder?

Comment: StringBuffer is synchronized, StringBuilder is not. That's it )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get whitespace because while your text is "dad", your buffer size is 1024, which means there is a lot of empty space in the buffer.

As byte is a primitive data type, the contents of the empty space in the buffer cannot be null, and instead default to 0, which is interpreted as white space when you convert it to a String.

Comment: Thank you @RaghavSood, you've answered my question in a meaningful way I can understand :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is in Raghav Sood's answer. You can overcome it by using:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read = 0; // saves how many bytes were actually read
while ((read = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    // don't use the complete buffer, only the used part of it.
    fileContent.append(new String(buffer, 0, read));
}
String myVariable = fileContent.toString();
```